# Proof verification: If $g\circ f$ is surjective, show that $g$ is surjective.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Let $X,Y,Z$ be sets and $f: X\to Y$, $g: Y\to Z$ functions. If $g\circ f$ is surjective, prove that $g$ is surjective.

Here's my **sketch**:

[image]

Since $g\circ f  : X\to Z$ is surjective, there are for every $z\in Z$ at least one $x\in X$ with $f(z)=x$. This means that $\#X \geq \# Z$ . Furthermore, we know that every $x\in X$ will mapped to $f(x)=y$. $g$ can only map $g(y)=z$ with $y$ being the elements of the image of $f$. Ultimately, the amount of $y=f(x)$-values is dependent on the amount of values in $Z$. There can never be more Elements $f(x)=y\in Y$ then there are elements in $Z$. Hence $g$ is surjective.

I hope you get what I just wrote since it is really hard to explain in English.

Comment: Take an element $z$ of $Z$. Since $g\circ f$ is surjective, there is an element $x$ of $X$ such that $g(f(x))=z$. Now consider the element $f(x)$ of $Y$. What can you conclude about $f$?

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need to argue with elements:

Since $f(X) \subseteq Y$, we have $Z = g(f(X)) \subseteq g(Y) \subseteq Z$, which implies $g(Y)=Z$, and $g$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c \in Z \implies a \in X$ such that $(g\circ f)(a) = c$. This is true since $(g\circ f)$ is onto. But $(g\circ f)(a) = g(f(a))$. So if you put $b = f(a) \in Y$, then $g(b) = c$, proving $g$ onto. I think this notation is easier to remember than yours...

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that
$$\forall z \in Z \exists y \in Y(z=f(y))$$
Let z in Z.
$f \circ g$ iz `onto`, so let x in X so that $z=(f \circ g)(x) $
$g(x) \in Y$
Well, we found element y in Y - $g(x)$ - so that $z=f(y)$. And so we proved that $f$ is `onto`.